# como retirar linhas de uma tabela?

Tags: html

Estou criando uma tabela, mas no site aparecem sempre as linhas que separam as colunas e linhas. Alguém pode informar-me como eu poderia fazer para tirá-las?

O código que tenho é este:

```html
<table>
   <tbody>

      <tr>
          <td bgcolor="white" width="175">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          <td bgcolor="white" width="25"></td>
          <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>

          <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          <td bgcolor="white" width="25"></td>
          <<td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
          <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
          <td bgcolor="white" width="25"></td>
          <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
          </td>
      </tr>

   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Na sua segunda linha, na última coluna, há `<<td`. Por favor, confirme se isso não foi erro de digitação na pergunta ou se seu código está assim mesmo. Isso quebra a sintaxe do HTML.

Comment: Ué sua tabela já está sem as linhas!! Só está com um erro como disse o Anderson.

Answer (score 2):

Basta você remover as bordas via css e pelos atributos `cellpadding` e `cellspacing`

```css
body {
  background-color: grey;
}

table {
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<h1> Atributos zerados</h1>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="white" width="175">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td bgcolor="white" width="25"></td>
      <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td bgcolor="white" width="25"></td>
      <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td bgcolor="white" width="25"></td>
      <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<h1> Apresentação default </h1>
<table>
  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="white" width="175">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td bgcolor="white" width="25"></td>
      <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td bgcolor="white" width="25"></td>
      <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</td>
      <td bgcolor="white" width="25"></td>
      <td bgcolor="white">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

nesse caso você pode acrescentar um estilo CSS na tag `<table>`, como  abaixo:

`<table style="border:0;">`

Essa é a solução mais atual, porém você também pode colocar o atributo `border="0"` na tag:

`<table border="0">`